# Rendering partial with ajax and json response

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to render a partial calling an ajax function and render it in a div.

In the code below, the `request.responseText` gives me the html I want but why does this response go into error function and not success? 
It seems quite simple but I am missing something here.
The post response status code is "200 OK" in chrome's inspect element

js code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/upload/get_detail.json",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { id: id },
            success: function(result) {
                $('.some-label').html(result);
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                alert(request.responseText);
            }
        }).done(function() {
           //some code
        });
```

controller:

```
  def get_detail
    @logs = Detail.where('category_id = ?', params[:id].to_i).limit(20)
    render :partial => "/category/detail", :layout=> false
  end
```

Comment: What does the responseText look like?

Comment: Most likely your *"html"* is not json.

Comment: It's an HTML. Actually, good question because I forgot to include the important part, the error: `Unexpected token <`

Comment: Correct. Your dataType is set to JSON, but you are returning HTML. Therefore jQuery sees the request as a failure because JSON !== HTML. If you want to return html, set your dataType to "html" or remove the dataType all together.

Comment: That's about right. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending HTML from the server, but you have configured your `jQuery.ajax` call to expect JSON. Change the `dataType` property to `html` and it should work.